# Randomly showing the image inside the page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried with fadeIn fadeOut of the image continuously here and there inside the page. I tried with window height. But that image appearing is overflow the width of the window. Here is the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aB8yq/)**
Is there is a way to show the image randomly inside the window without overflow or anything.
Here is the

```
  var clone = drop
                    .clone()
                    .appendTo('body')

                    .css('left', Math.random() * jQuery(window).width() - 100)
                            .css('top', snowTop)
                    .html('<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9o1r.png"/>')
                    .animate({
            }, 20000, function() {
                jQuery(this).fadeIn(2000, function() {

                    jQuery(this).fadeOut(2000);
                });
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try following code....I have just used innerHeight and innerWeight instead of height and width. Also changed snowTop to following..

```
var snowTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * (windowHeight-128)); //here 128 is image height..you should provide actual height of image instead of 128
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aB8yq/12/)

JS:

```
    jQuery(function() {
        var windowHeight = jQuery(window).innerHeight();
        var drop = jQuery('.drop2').detach();

        var wh = jQuery(window).innerHeight();
        var ww = jQuery(window).innerWidth();
        var fh = jQuery('.drop2').innerHeight();
        var fw = jQuery('.drop2').innerWidth();
        function create() {


            var snowTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * (windowHeight-128));
            var number1 = windowHeight - 500 + Math.floor(Math.random() * windowHeight);
            var number2 = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 28);
            var number3 = 9 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
            var number4 = 13 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
            var number5 = 17 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
            var imageSize = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
            //alert(imageSize);

            if (imageSize > 15) {
                var customsize = Math.random(1 * 1000) + 9000;
            } else {
                var customsize = Math.random(1 * 1000) + 15000;
            }



            // alert(number1);

            var clone = drop
                    .clone()
                    .appendTo('body')

                    .css('left', Math.random() * jQuery(window).innerWidth() - 128)
                            .css('top', snowTop)
                    .html('<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9o1r.png"/>')
                    .animate({
            }, 20000, function() {
                jQuery(this).fadeIn(2000, function() {

                    jQuery(this).fadeOut(2000);
                });
                jQuery(this).click(function() {
                    alert("Happy Holidays");
                });
                jQuery(this).hover(
                        function() {
                            jQuery(this).append(jQuery("<div id='new' style='width:100px;height:100px;color:#fff;'>Happy Holidays</div>"));
                        }, function() {
                    jQuery(this).find("div:last").remove();
                }
                );


            });


        }


setInterval(create, 1000);



    });
```

Comment: Even when using innerWidth, you still need to update the 'left' calculation like you did 'snowTop'. Like this: .css('left', Math.random() * (jQuery(window).width() - 128))

Comment: @rusmus I think OP is already doing -100 for left, but yes I have updated code for left. Thanks..:)

Comment: Thanks @Nikhil I tried that fiddle for the left side is not showing properly ?

Answer (score 1):

Your snowTop must not be greater then 450 as its spacing from top of your parent container and your left must be greater then 0 as its spacing from left of your parent container.

The problem is only with your css in this line

```
.css('left', left).css('top', snowTop)
```

**you must make sure your left spacing should not be less than 0 and your top must also not exceed a max limit(here i've taken 450 as per my screen resolution and page size).**
This works for me,try it.

```
jQuery(function () {

                var windowHeight = jQuery(window).height();
                var drop = jQuery('.drop2').detach();

                var wh = jQuery(window).height();
                var ww = jQuery(window).width();
                var fh = jQuery('.drop2').outerHeight();
                var fw = jQuery('.drop2').outerWidth();
                function create() {

                    var left = Math.random() * jQuery(window).width() - 100;
                    if (left < 0)
                        left = 1;
                    var snowTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * (windowHeight));
                    if (snowTop > 450)
                        snowTop = 450;
                    var number1 = windowHeight - 500 + Math.floor(Math.random() * windowHeight);
                    var number2 = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 28);
                    var number3 = 9 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
                    var number4 = 13 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
                    var number5 = 17 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
                    var imageSize = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
                    //alert(imageSize);

                    if (imageSize > 15) {
                        var customsize = Math.random(1 * 1000) + 9000;
                    } else {
                        var customsize = Math.random(1 * 1000) + 15000;
                    }



                    // alert(number1);

                    var clone = drop
                        .clone()
                        .appendTo('body')

                        .css('left', left)
                                .css('top', snowTop)
                        .html('<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9o1r.png"/>')
                        .animate({
                    }, 20000, function () {
                        jQuery(this).fadeIn(2000, function () {

                            jQuery(this).fadeOut(2000);
                        });
                        jQuery(this).click(function () {
                            alert("Happy Holidays");
                        });
                        jQuery(this).hover(
                            function () {
                                jQuery(this).append(jQuery("<div id='new' style='width:100px;height:100px;color:#fff;'>Happy Holidays</div>"));
                            }, function () {
                                jQuery(this).find("div:last").remove();
                            }
                    );


                    });


                }


                setInterval(create, 1000);



            });
```

Comment: Welcome :)
i really liked your question,it was quiet different from other questions which i answered...